Two boys: how and when will their relationship change?
I have two boys, one is 4y4m, the other is 2y5m. At this time they're finally starting to play pretty well and more cooperatively with each other. Although we do still need to be around because hitting still happens and tempers flare.
What I'm curious to know is how their relationship with each other is likely to evolve in the next number of years. At what age are we going to be able to step away from them more fully and just let them play? And what will happen after that stage? Basically just wanting to get an idea of how and when it's likely to evolve from the standpoint of how we'll need to parent them.

This is dependent on a lot of things, and will vary. E.g. Who is still hitting? How long can they play well now? Most kids learn to lie around age 3. has that started yet? Etc. Thanks.

Nothing out of the ordinary, just two thoughtful boys who still have some back and forth occasionally. It's all age appropriate. If anything likely slightly mature for their age. The older one lies, younger one not yet.

I think this is impossible to predict. There will be phases were they get along great, phases where they ignore each other and phases where they will be at each other's throat. These things come and go more or less randomly. It depends a lot on their personalities and what overlapping (or not) interests they will develop.

My experience has been that a lot of what kids and siblings do is psychologically consistent with age, so I thought I'd give the question a try. But if this one doesn't work fair enough. I'm mostly just interested to know when the violence will completely settle and they'll be somewhat responsible.

We have a son and a daughter with a similar age gap (right now they just turned 5 & 7, respectively). In a general sense, they reached a point of being able to play together without supervision in the last year or so.
Conflict Resolution & Self-Sufficiency
Prior to that, the younger one would start to feel frustrated and sometimes hit the other. Alternately, the older would antagonize the younger either on purpose or on accident and a fight would break out.
During this time (i.e. them being 3-4 & 5-6), we spent a lot of energy on conflict resolution techniques for both of them (more than a few situations where they both needed to apologize to the other). In particular, with the younger learning to express his feelings with his words first and then to come ask for help if that didn't work. For the older, we focused on her listening to and recognizing a 'no' when it was being given as well as not talking over her brother. This was especially important for the dynamic between our kids because the older was an early talker while the younger often struggled with being as communicative.
Additionally, we spent a fair bit of energy on helping the kids to take care of themselves. For example, we regularly keep cut up fruit in the fridge for them to take as an anytime snack; we had to work really hard on potty training; we involve them in cleaning things up regularly; we continually teach them the difference between tools and toys; and we focus on the concept of doing dangerous things safely. In general, we want them to know what they can do on their own and let them explore their limits within reason.
Terrible Twos
I will note, you are in a stage that's before the time I've described. I'm sure you've heard the phrase 'terrible twos' and there's some truth to that. We found that for both our kids at that age, there's a lot of difficult learning happening as our kids learned to talk and it can become overwhelming for them quickly leading to tantrums that are difficult to quell. This continued into their third year as well.
During the 'terrible twos' stage, we did NOT try and make the younger apologize or engage in conflict resolution. Part of the reason for this is that we didn't think it was something he was ready to engage with or even fully understand; we felt he was too busy just understanding his own feelings and emotions. To that end, we advised the older one that she needed to come ask for help if the younger was doing something she wanted to stop because it was unlikely that he would be able to fully understand things.
Current Day
As I stated upfront, they are generally at a point right now where they can play together without supervision. Even still, periodic checkins are prudent lest we have another Riceboat Incident1. But things like that are just kids exploring the world around them without adults to guide them and while there was a mess to clean up, part of me was glad that they had fun together and even tried to fix something together.
But with things like the weather being nice, we can tell them to go play in the backyard and things are generally ok. We're on the verge of letting them play in the front yard as well. They're allowed to ride their bikes on the street provided they can still see us. There's definitely going to be more problems that occur in time, but for now we focus our efforts on trying to teach them how to solve things for themselves and it's generally worked well.
Advice for You
We were very deliberate in the age gap of our kids and part of that was to allow them to be friends with each other. It sounds like your sons right now are friends with each other and I think so long as you continue to work towards developing that friendship you should eventually reach a point where you can just walk away.
Our journey took a few years to occur because that's what our kids needed. There's no real magic endpoint for this. It might just happen one Saturday that you suddenly wake up and it's 9 am and you realize your kids woke up early without waking you, didn't fight with each other, and over an hour managed to build a blanket fort that's made the living room nigh impossible to walk through. Fingers crossed they didn't spill a bowl of cereal in there. But even if they did, not a big deal, you can clean it up together.
1 They were playing in a downstairs bathroom with a toy boat. For reasons of "they wanted to be scientists" they had put at least 2 pounds of rice in the boat, filled it with water and water flavorings. At some point, this endeavor got away from them and I'm guessing some (a lot?) of water was spilled. When I came home later that evening, I found the bathroom door locked, a space heater running on the floor, and a fan going as well.

Had our two sons about 18 months apart.
The relationship changes over time.
The most challenging was when they were about 16 and 14.
They had been arguing and fought. The older one found out that his brother was stronger than he thought.
Big discussion with both - to point out that fighting was not worth it, they need to discuss, disagree and leave the room if necessary. Also pointed out that the most trustworthy person they have to talk to (after mum & I have gone) is each other and their sister.
Now they have a great relationship, they helped each other with homework and have even lent each other significant money - they are now about 24 & 22...
Work with them and show them what they have - emotions are hard to control sometimes - give them a structure.

How quickly they learn to play without conflict is mostly dependent on their personalities. For example, an impulsive and stimulation-seeking child (e.g. with ADHD) can take a lot more maturity to manage conflict and frustration.
However, your guidance as a parent is also impactful in how they learn to hear each other, and creatively think of solutions for moments of disagreement.  For example, demonstrating asking vs. demanding, taking turns (possibly looking at a clock for how long the turn is) and preferring games that encourage cooperation.
